# Java Method return concrete type from generic return type

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to make an enum list, and have an abstract method defined in the enum, which each enum value implements. The problem I am facing is that the abstract class has a generic return type but I want each enum value to return a concrete type.
I'll give an example:

```
public enum Attributes {
    name {
        @Override
        public void createAttribute(Person person) {
            //Do some validations
            //Save in some storage
        }
        @Override
        public Name getAttribute(Person person) {
            // Validations
            // Retreive from storage
            return new Name("test");
        }
    },
    address {
        @Override
        public void createAttribute(Person person) {
            //Do some validations
            //Save in some storage
        }
        @Override
        public Address getAttribute(Person person) {
            // Validations
            // Retreive from storage
            return new Name("test");
        }
    }

    public abstract Object getAttribute(Person person);
    public abstract void createAttribute(Person person);
}
```

Here the issue is that I would need to do typecasting to get the concrete object which is not recommended and I don't get any type of safety. How Should I go about so that using the enum value I can get my concrete object instead of the generic one.

Now I wanna call this as,

```
Arrays.stream(Attributes.values()).forEach(r -> {
    r.createAttribute(person);
}
final Address address = Attributes.address.getAttribute(person);
final Name name = Attributes.name.getAttribute(person);
```

So now whenever I need to add a new attribute I don't want to write create methods for it in the Person class every time. I just add it to enum and it gets created. But now since I have the create method in the enum, I also want the getAttribute to be present here.

Comment: Changing it to `public abstract <T extends Animal> T getObject()` will remove the need to type-cast, but won't be type-safe.

Comment: Why do you need to cast the object to the concrete type?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Can't you just add an `Address getAddress()` and `Name getName()` method to `Person`?

Comment: It's still not clear how this makes sense.  If one wants to extract attributes of a `Person`, then why would one not use methods of class `Person`, or at most a utility class offering a specific method for each supported attribute?

Comment: Suppose I want to keep adding 100's of attributes. I do not want to every time write new methods to the Person Class. I want them to be enums and use the same method to extract them. Having all attributes in enum gives me a consolidated list of them.

Comment: So instead of adding methods to `Person`, you want to add instances *and* their idiosyncratic methods to a separate enum?  (*Plus* whatever needs to go into `Person` to support them?) I'm not seeing what's gained.  I'm especially not seeing it in light of the actual question posed, which supposes that client code needs to know details of what attributes they're retrieving *anyway*.  If in fact they do need that, then invoking a attribute-specific methods is a far more appropriate way to achieve it.

Comment: I think I am not clear in explaining my question. Does it make a little sense now?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It remains completely unclear how this gains anything worth having.  But more importantly for us here, now, it's unclear what you want to be able to do, yet can't.  The usage example you've added at the end will work as it stands, or at least it would if the syntax errors were corrected..

Comment: The create part will work but not the get part.

Answer (score 0):

> Here the issue is that I would need to do typecasting to get the concrete object which is not recommended and I don't get any type of safety.

You're right.  Given an enum type `E` with an associated enum constant `C`, the type of the expression `E.C` is `E`. Java provides no mechanism for naming or representing a narrower type for that expression.  One of the implications is that although an enum instance can implement methods with covariant return types, the covariance is not visible outside the instance.  If you depend for some purpose on the narrower return type of one of those instances' methods, then casting is your only alternative.

And you're right that such casts are not type safe.  They cannot be checked by the compiler, and in practice, you as programmer can get them wrong.  But the information to perform a compile-time check is not expressed by the language, so there is no scope for a workaround in the language as it is defined today.

> How Should I go about so that using the enum value I can get my concrete object instead of the generic one.

You *should* choose an altogether different approach, not involving an enum.

If you stuck with the enum then you would have to adopt an approach that relies on the enum instances to perform any tasks that depend on their own particular characteristics.  Because you ask so persistently, one possibility would be to implement a variation on double dispatch.  Instead of a `getObject()` method, you would have something like

```
void acceptReceiver(AttributeReceiver r, Person p);
```

paired with

```
public interface AttributeReceiver {
    default void receiveName(Name name) { /* empty */ }
    default void receiveAddress(Address addr) { /* empty */ }
}
```

Of course, the enum instances would have to implement `acceptReceiver` appropriately.

You would probably want to use that a little more directly than just to retrieve attributes, but you *could* use it to retrieve attributes something like this:

```
class Example {
    Name name;
    Address address;

    void retrieveAttributes(Person person) {    
        AttributeReceiver receiver = new AttributeReceiver() {
            public void receiveName(Name n) { name = n; }
            public void receiveAddress(Address a) { addr = a; }
        };
        Attributes.name.acceptReceiver(receiver, person);
        Attributes.address.acceptReceiver(receiver, person);
    }
}
```

But that's ***awfully*** roundabout when you have the alternative of using (just) *methods*, whether on `Person` or even on some non-enum utility class.  I continue not to see any advantage to involving an enum here.  I think your code overall would be more complex and harder to understand and maintain with enums than without.

The root issue is that you are abstracting away details that you actually care about.  That's a deep design flaw.  You can program your way around it, but it would be better to choose a more appropriate level of abstraction in the first place.